# Supabase client doesn't fetch anything

Tags: vue.js, vite, supabase

First of all, sorry if I make english mistakes
I'm making this side-project for fun using Vue3 & Vite and it's my first time using Supabase

I created the 'players' table in the Supabase dashboard and added two rows for testing purposes.
I used createClient to initialize the client :

```js
// client.js
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js"

const supabaseInfos = {
    url: "https://example.supabase.co",
    key: "example"
}

export const client = createClient(supabaseInfos.url, supabaseInfos.key)
```

Then I used the client in order to make a Player Controller :

```js
// Player.js
import { client } from "../../lib/client";

export default class Player {

    static async index() {
        return await client.from('players').select('*')
    }

    static async show(id) {
        return await client.from('players').select('*').match({ id })
    }

    static async create(data) {
        return await client.from('players').insert(data)
    }

    static async update(id, data) {
        return await client.from('players').update(data).match({ id })
    }

    static async delete(id) {
        return await client.from('players').delete().match({ id })
    }
}
```

Please take note that I'm using [the official documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select)

The main problem is, it doesn't work. The client isn't fetching any data, what it all do is returning an empty array.

```js
// App.vue
<template>
    <ul v-if="players.length > 0">
        <li v-for="player in players" :key="player.id">{{ player.name }}</li>
    </ul>
    <p v-else>No player found.</p>
</template>

<script>
import Player from './assets/controllers/Player'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            players: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getAllPlayers() {
            const { data } = await Player.index()
            this.players = data

            console.log(data) // returns an empty array
            console.log(this.players) // returns an empty Proxy object
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getAllPlayers()
    },
}
</script>
```

I really don't understand why the client never returns anything. I got the api key and url right and my database is public. It returns a 200 code but there's nothing to use when the Promise comes

Instead of using `createClient`, I instanciated a SupabaseClient, which changed nothing at all. I also tried to use `client.query()` but it didn't work either...

Comment: What are the [RLS](https://supabase.com/docs/learn/auth-deep-dive/auth-row-level-security) set for these tables?  Do you get the data with the `service_role` key?

Comment: RLS is enabled but there are no policies yet, aren't they optionnal? I used the anon key

Comment: they are not optional, and you will always get an empty array. try to disable or add READ RLS for "using(true)" - default template could be used